# Getter returning correctly, then changes to null

Tags: java, javafx, setter, getter

So I'm having an unusual issue where code is detecting the current user with the method `getCurrentUser()` but when I use it later to check which user borrowed a book it returns null.

I also attempted changing line 3 of borrowBook method to the currentUser variable, and also tried getting the info through usernameTxtField.getText()

```
public class Controller {
private Book HFJ = new Book("HFJ", "SI & BA","5678",3, 1);

@FXML
private void attemptLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    String usernameInput = usernameTxtField.getText();
    String passwordInput = passwordTxtField.getText();
    boolean loginSuccessful = false;


    switch (usernameInput.toLowerCase()) {
        case "user1":
            if (passwordInput.equals("Password1")) {
                System.out.println("Login Successful");
                informationLabel.setText("Login Successful");
                loginSuccessful = true;
                currentUser = usernameInput.toLowerCase();
            }
            break;
        case "user2":
            if (passwordInput.equals("Password2")) {
                System.out.println("Login Successful");
                informationLabel.setText("Login Successful");
                loginSuccessful = true;
                currentUser = usernameInput.toLowerCase();
            }
            break;
        case "user3":
            if (passwordInput.equals("Password3")) {
                System.out.println("Login Successful");
                informationLabel.setText("Login Successful");
                loginSuccessful = true;
                currentUser = usernameInput.toLowerCase();
            }
            break;
        case "user4":
            if (passwordInput.equals("Password4")) {
                System.out.println("Login Successful");
                informationLabel.setText("Login Successful");
                loginSuccessful = true;
                currentUser = usernameInput.toLowerCase();
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Incorrect username or Password");
            informationLabel.setText("Incorrect username or Password");
            break;
    }

    if (loginSuccessful == true) {
        Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home.fxml"));
        Scene home_scene = new Scene(home);
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        primaryStage.setScene(home_scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        currentUser = usernameInput.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(getCurrentUser());
        homeLoginInfoLabel.setText("Login Successful");
    }
}
@FXML private Label HFJQuantity = new Label();
@FXML private Button HFJBorrowBtn = new Button();
@FXML
private void borrowBook(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    if(HFJ.getQuantity()>=1){
        HFJ.setQuantity(HFJ.getQuantity() -1);
        System.out.println("Book Borrowed By: " + getCurrentUser());//CONSOLE PRINT
        HFJQuantity.setText("" + HFJ.getQuantity());
        Parent borrowSuccessful = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("borrowSuccess.fxml"));
        Scene success_scene = new Scene(borrowSuccessful);
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        primaryStage.setScene(success_scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not enough books");
        HFJBorrowBtn.setDisable(true);
    }

}


private String getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
}
```

When I run the code and login this is what the console prints:

```
Login Successful
user1
Book Borrowed By: null
```

Why isn't it recognising the current user? Any help would be great

Comment: where is "currentUser" defined?

Comment: You haven't even included the part of the code that is responsible for printing `null`. Provide a [mcve], and especially pay attention to **Minimal**.

Comment: @Gendarme yes he did. It's in the borrow book method. He also put a comment next to it that says "console print"

Comment: My bad. I don't know how my `Ctrl + F` missed that. This is still not a complete example, though.

Comment: Could you please show the content of home.fxml and borrowSuccess.fxml files?

Comment: @Alex, yes I completely misread something so I removed the comment :)

Comment: Are you using this class for the controllers from two different FXML files?

Comment: @James_D I'm using this controller for all FXML files

Comment: @AlexR my bad, it should have been as a global variable, I was trying to cut out unnecessary code to make it easier to troubleshoot on here and forgot to add it back in.

Comment: @Donald What you actually mean is you're using this *class* for all the controllers for the different FXML files. Every time you load an FXML file you get a new controller. Use a different class for the controllers from each FXML file - it is impossible to keep track of which fields are initialized and which are null otherwise (as you have discovered). Presumably `attemptLogin()` is called in one controller and `getCurrentUser()` is called in a different controller.

Comment: @James_D is there an easy way to implement multiple controllers and have the controllers communicate, i.e. I need to get the current user information from the controller for the login fxml whilst in the borrow book fxml in order to keep track of which user has borrowed which book

Comment: @Donald http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is down to scope. I can't see in this class where you have declared currentUser outside of the switch statement or the if/else. Try initialising currentUser at the top with your other class variable.